# Codeigniter force download CSV prevent auto format remove leading zero

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel, codeigniter-3, export-to-csv

I have an issue with the **CSV** file when I download it using **CodeIgniter** default **force download function** then the item number that starts from the zero is missed how I get this on the excel file.
please tell me if you know how to show leading zero in CSV.
please see the screenshot all items start from zero but excel not show

- http://prntscr.com/kebaoj

here is my code
in the **$rows[ ]** all the data that i want to export in the excel.

```
$content = array_to_spreadsheet($rows);

        $this->user_log->add_employee_activity(lang('activity_items_export') ,lang('activity_item'), lang('yes'));
        force_download('items_export.' . ($this->config->item('spreadsheet_format') == 'XLSX' ? 'xlsx' : 'csv'), $content);
        exit;
```

Comment: Numbers don't start with 0 so change the cell format for that column to text or something.

Comment: I fix it, bro, thanks. But i Add char(160) with that field. that generate a space with string then excel is not detect zero.